# Python: Redis as session backend to Beaker

Tags: python, session, pylons, redis, beaker

Anyone had success with using Redis as Beaker backend? Can you tell me link or library how to do it? I am looking for any library which does this but could not get anything out of google search.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have posted to pylons user group and this information resolve my question..

http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/msg/a1144aa1ca8e0417

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. easy_install redis
2. easy_install pip
3. pip install git+git://github.com/bbangert/beaker_extensions.git
4. Edit Pylons' development.ini

   ```
   [app:main]
   full_stack = true
   static_files = true

   cache_dir = %(here)s/data
   beaker.session.type = redis
   beaker.session.url:127.0.0.1:6379
   beaker.session.key = appname
   ```
5. (Optional)
   Edit this file and change the serialization method to JSON. Even
   though JSON is not as efficient byte for byte I like how it is easily
   readable and relatively well supported across the technologies I've
   chosen:

https://github.com/bbangert/beaker_extensions/blob/master/beaker_extensions/redis_.py

Posted by Jeff Tchang